# How to embed multiple Xml fragments in a single resource file in C# 2005?

Tags: c#, xml, resources

My C# 2005 application needs to work with several small Xml fragments. I want to type them verbatim, but the problem with using verbatim string literals is that I need to escape the actual quote inside Xml with another quote for C# compiler to understand.

On the other hand, if I store them in a file and embed that file as a resource, then for each of the several Xml fragments, I need to create a separate resource file. Ideally what I want is a mechanism where:

1. I can store all the Xml fragments in a single file, with separate name or identifier for each Xml fragment, and
2. I can type the Xml as it is without escaping quotes and I can type them in multi line with indenting for easier readability

Is there any mechanism it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the xml fragments into a single xml document. Load the document and then extract the fragments programmatically as you need them. They are easily located with `myDoc["fragmentName"]`

When loading an XmlDocument, use the PreserveWhitespace setting to preserve newlines and indentation. You probably can't get away without quoting special chars.

Comment: How do I give an identifier to each xml fragment within the text file. The fragments are not related, so they will not have a common root node. Can you give a small example with 2 fragments?